# How to set up mail in terminal to use email?

Tags: command-line, email

I would like to use the terminal to send emails. How should I proceed?

Comment: Local mail in your network or world wide? Give me a ping with @A.B. -

Comment: mutt is very simple to use. I'd suggest that

Comment: I wouldn't call mutt simple, but it's definitely badass. It's like the vim of email.

Comment: To **voters**: I don't expect to find **that** many mail programs for the command-line - why would this question be "too broad"?

Comment: Perhaps this guide might be helpful: http://www.andrews-corner.org/mutt.html

Comment: Try `alpine` or `mutt`.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to send emails, do this.

Install *ssmtp* with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install ssmtp
```

Open up the *ssmtp* configuration file with:

```
sudo vim /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
```

and edit the file so it looks like this:

```
root=YOURUSERNAME@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
AuthUser=YOURUSERNAME
AuthPass=YOURPASSWORD
UseSTARTTLS=YES
UseTLS=YES
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
```

The above is an example with gmail. You have to change the *mailhub* and *root* lines if you're not using gmail. (For yahoo mail change the mailhub line to *mailhub=smtp.mail.yahoo.com:587*)

After this is done you will be able to send mail like this:

```
echo "Test message" | mail -s "Test subject" user@gmail.com
```

Comment: I've tried and I'm getting the following:

Comment: msmtp: no recipients found
mail: Sending data to /usr/bin/msmtp failed: Process exited with a non-zero status
mail: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status

Comment: It seems like ssmtp is conflicting with msmtp. The error message you show here is from antoher smtp client called mstmp. Try to send like this instead, do command "ssmtp user@gmail.com" --> press ENTER --> write something --> and then end with pressing Ctrl + d.

Comment: Also make sure the "mailutils" package is installed in your system. To install it do --> "sudo apt-get install mailtuils"

Comment: tried to install "mailutils" and get the following message: "E: Unable to locate package mailtuils"

Comment: This "E: Unable to locate package mailtuils" says you tried to install mailtuils, you switched place on t and u. Try again to install mailutils.

Comment: done! tried  >   "ssmtp user@gmail.com" --> press ENTER --> write something --> and then end with pressing Ctrl + d.    and  get the following: ssmtp: Authorization failed (535 5.7.0 (#AUTH003) Incorrect username or password.)

Comment: This error message could be due to a couple of things, 1. You've entered wrong password/username, 2. You have special characters in your password like "# + =". 3. Your yahoo/gmail/isp account is blocking you sending email from "less" secure applications (this can sometimes be disabled in account settings).

Comment: Attempt to add `UseTLS=YES` and `mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587` to your config file to use with GMail per https://wiki.debian.org/sSMTP